# jQuery: Loop through JSON document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have the following JSON structure on "y" location:

```
{"results":[{
    "a_id":4529245,
    "type":"a",
    "name":"HONDA"
},{
    "a_id":1234567,
    "type":"l",
    "name":"Autos Marron"
}]}
```

Inside my JS document I have the following code:

```
    var i;
    i=0;
    $.getJSON('/document/location', function( data ) {

        console.log(data);

        $.each( data, function( key, val ) {

            var contentString = '<span>'+
            val[i].name +
            '</span>';

            $('#info').append(contentString);

            i++;
        });
    });
```

I searched online and I readed that I would be able to do **val.name** and would be able to print each of the "name" variables inside my JSON document.

But I have to use a incrementing variable (i) in order to print **only** the first variable that equals to "HONDA" using **val[i].name**

I'd like to print all variables called name. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Still not clear what exactly you want.. "...But I have to use a incrementing variable (i) in order to print only the first variable that equals to "HONDA" using val[i].name

I'd like to print all variables called name."

Comment: You want to print just `honda` or all the values of 'name' attribute ?

Comment: @ChintanSoni sorry if I didn't explain good enough myself (not a native english speaker)... I want to print all values of 'name' attribute. I'm not able to loop trough all of this 'name' attributes with my current code

Comment: And when I use the codes in the answers already given, I get "undefined" on the browser's console if I do **console.log(val.name)**

Comment: Daniel, provide your "/document/location" content, what their content ?, show it

Comment: @wZVanG I thought it wasn't necessary, I'm using laravel so it is **request_uri_map : "{{URL::route('agencies-json-all')}}",** translated it would be like www.site.com/json/agencies/all -- I'm sure the document is well located since I was able to print only the first value of the 'name' attribute with my code on the original question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to loop `data.results` as this is the array you want to access:

`Code`

```
$.getJSON('/document/location', function( data ) {

    console.log(data);

    $.each( data.results, function(key,val ) {

        var contentString = '<span>'+
        val.name +
        '</span>';

        $('#info').append(contentString);

    });
});
```

** In your code when you loop through data you get:

val as

```
[{
            "a_id":4529245,
            "type":"a",
            "name":"HONDA"
        },{
            "a_id":1234567,
            "type":"l",
            "name":"Autos Marron"
        }]
```

and key as `results`

Now since val is an array to display name you had to do `data[index].name`

`Edit:`

Here is working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/boLc5240/1/)

Comment: Using your code I'm doing a **console.log(val.name)** and I get undefined on my Chrome browser console

Comment: Thank you, it works as expected now, I had to leave (key, val) on the $.each line instead of just (val) as someone here mentioned. Again, many thanks

Answer (score 3):

Why not you make a simple `for` loop instead of using `$.each`.

**Try this:**

```
for(int i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    var contentString = '<span>'+
    data[i].name +
    '</span>';    
}
```

Comment: thank you but who is data? I'm accessing to an external document, data is not a local variable

Comment: data is the variable you stored your response to. I din't mentioned the whole code but just the snippet for you to understand :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$.each( data.results, function( val ) { // change data to data.results, and you are looping through an array so there is no key; only a val

    var contentString = '<span>'+
    val.name +
    '</span>';

    $('#info').append(contentString);

    // i++; You don't need i at all
});
```

Comment: Using your code I'm doing a **console.log(val.name)** and I get undefined on my Chrome browser console

Answer (score 1):

Ok.. First if all, if you are having `.json` file in other folder then, specify path to it:

Say, your directory structure is like:

```
|---data
    |---test.json
|---js
|---css
|---index.html
```

Then, your code looks like:

```
$.getJSON("data/test.json", function(json) {
    console.log(json); // this will show the info it in firebug console

    var tempData = "";
    $.each( json.results, function(index, element) {
        tempData  += '<span>'+element.name +'</span>';
    });
    $('#info').html(tempData);
});
```

**Note:** Its not good habit of traversing DOM for every element in loop. Like I saw in other answers. Say you got 100 elements in your array, then its worthless traversing DOM 100 times just to append 1 data at a time. So, you can optimise this to having variable that holds the data to be displayed in html, and after looping over the array, just use `.append("")` or `.html("")` depending on your need. Hope you got it..

Answer (score 1):

Having the following structure

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "a_id": 4529245,
            "type": "a",
            "name": "HONDA"
        },
        {
            "a_id": 1234567,
            "type": "l",
            "name": "Autos Marron"
        }
    ]
}
```

For a string better performance try

```
$.getJSON('/document/location', function( data ) {

    var buffer = [];

    $.each( data.results, function( index, entry )
    {
        buffer.push( '<span>', entry.name, '</span>' );
    });

    $('#info').append( buffer.join('') );
});
```

For safe code (to prevent injection) with better performance try

```
$.getJSON('/document/location', function( data ) {

    var box = document.createDocumentFragment();

    $.each( data.results, function( index, entry )
    {
        $( '<span>' ).text( entry.name ).appendTo( box );
    });

    $('#info').append( box );
});
```

Test safe and unsafe code in [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6otbL4f3/)

Comment: This is actually great info! thanks, I'm currently using pretty complex code with Google maps and I think I wouldn't know how to implement this but I will try. Again, thanks :)

Comment: Me gusta ayudar a quien lo necesite :)